# Mostrar Toast al final de la repetición del Dialog

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Buenas tardes, estoy realizando lo siguiente: Según la cantidad de Stock que ingrese en el siguiente formulario me generará esa cantidad de veces de Dialog que tienen EditText

Por ejemplo si en Stock ingreso el número 5:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me generará 5 veces un Dialog donde ingresaré información detallada, donde el título irá cambiando a medida que voy ingresando los datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que no entiendo es porque en el titulo me aparece: Producto 5/5, Producto 4/5, Producto 3/5, Producto 2/5, Producto 1/5. Cuando al programarlo le he puesto que lo muestre de la siguiente manera: Producto 1/5, Producto 2/5, Producto 3/5, Producto 4/5, Producto 5/5. Y también quiero que muestre un Toast después de haber agregado el último producto. El problema es que el Toast me lo muestra al ejecutar el evento Click. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
btnContinuar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int stock = Integer.parseInt(input_layout_stock.getEditText().getText().toString());
            for(int i = 1 ; i <= stock ; i++){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                builder.setTitle("Producto " + i + "/" + stock);
                //builder.setMessage("Agregar");
                builder.setView(R.layout.dialog_add_product);
                builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_product, null));
                builder.setPositiveButton("Continuar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
                builder.create();
                if(i == 5){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Se agregaron " + stock + " productos con éxito.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como menciona @idelcano, el problema se debe a que creas 5 dialogs diferentes, la mejor solución sería solo crear uno y fuera modificado dinámicamente, un ejemplo podría ser el siguiente:

```
btnContinuar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int stock = Integer.parseInt(input_layout_stock.getEditText().getText().toString());
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        int i=1;
        builder.setTitle("Producto " + i+ "/" + stock);
        //builder.setMessage("Agregar");
        builder.setView(R.layout.dialog_add_product);
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_product, null));
        builder.setPositiveButton("Continuar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if(stock==0){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Se agregaron " + i + " productos con éxito.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                dialog.cancel();
            }else{
                //guardamos en un arreglo los valores de Talla, Color y Precio
                //ponemos en blanco los textView
                builder.setTitle("Producto "+(++i)+"/" + stock);
            }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
        builder.create();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te está ocurriendo es que al hacer clic todo ese código se ejecuta en unos segundos. Por lo que se te abren 5 dialogs y te muestra el toast. Tu lo que ves es el último diálogo abierto y vas cerrandolos y viendo los primeros.

Deberías de mover la creación de nuevos dialogs y el toast final a dentro del diálogo. Y hacerlo modal para impedir que el usuario se vaya sin continuar el flujo de trabajo que hayas creado.

Supongo que tu variable stock puede ser una variable estática de clase y cuando das a continuar dentro del diálogo, si no es 0, te crea un nuevo diálogo.

Tal vez alguien tenga una respuesta mejor con una mejor práctica respecto a los dialogos.